# Google Cloud VPC Internet Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are testing google cloud, we have 1 VPC network with 2 server with only private ips + a bastion for ssh.

Big question : These servers need access to internet but it seems that in GCE you don't have this kind of service like in AWS (Internet gateway).

Am i wrong ? I really don't want to instantiate VM for Internet gateway.

I saw a route "default-internet-gateway" but i don't think it is working

Answer (score 5):

Currently, the right way is to use Cloud NAT, documentation can be found here:

> ### [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)
>
> Cloud NAT (network address translation) allows Google Cloud Platform (GCP) virtual machine (VM) instances without external IP addresses and private Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters to connect to the Internet.

And here is the explanation how to set this up:

> ### [Using Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/using-nat)
>
> *Introduction*
> This page shows you how to configure Cloud NAT. Before setting up Cloud NAT, read the Cloud NAT Overview.
>
> Note: Cloud NAT uses Cloud Router only to group NAT configuration information (control plane). Cloud NAT does not direct a Cloud Router to use BGP or to add routes. NAT traffic does not pass through a Cloud Router (data plane).

Answer (score 3):

That's not really how that works.

You can't access the internet from those instances because you removed the public IPs from your instances. The NAT (1:1) is performed by Google between the instance's public IP to its private IP, with the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) as you specify (which can be tag-based). There's a default implicit "deny all ingress" and "allow all egress" rule, so add rules to permit access as desired. Otherwise, if you want to permit access only via a bastion host, give the instances public IPs and don't add any ingress allow rules, and they'll be able to access the internet.

If you still want to do everything yourself, then [you can](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations).